# symfony2 - Creating services with variable name

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

Let's say I have 50 classes which perform database operations via a DBAL connection.
Now I want to make these classes as services with the DBAL connection injected when instantiated.

I call one of those services method with:

```
$results = $this->get('my_service')->someMethod();
```

with the service defined as:

```
services:
  my_service:
    class:  Acme\BundleName\Entity\ModelClass
    arguments:  [@database_connection]
```

is there any way to make that "my_service" variable?

Ideally, I would have one service, who accepts the name of the model class, and automatically instantiate and injects it with the DBAL connection. Without defining 50 services for 50 classes.
The 50 classes only need the same injection, the DBAL connection.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- generate the services in a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html), using an [abstract parent service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parentservices.html)
- use a [service factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) to initialize the service

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried to use a service factory as documented in the symfony book, but, if I am not wrong, there are no variables, the name of the classes must still be defined one by one in the YAML file. Same for the Abstract parent class. Could you give me an example?